# A set of functions which is open in the space $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a $C^1$ and increasing
 function such that

$i)$ If $f(p)=p$ then $|f'(p)|\ne 1$

I want to prove that there exist an $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $g\in C^1$ and $||f-g||_{C^1}<\varepsilon$ then $g$ also have the two properties.

I don't know if this definition requires some other property to the function $f$, but it's something like this (maybe it's this)

The norm $||.||_{C^1}$ is defined on the space $C^1[0,1]$ by $||g'||_{C^1} = ||g||_{\infty}+||g'||_{\infty}= \sup_{x\in [0,1]}{|g(x)|}+\sup_{x\in [0,1]}{|g'(x)|}$

EDIT: I considered two assumptions, but as someone said before $i) \Rightarrow  ii)$ so I'll only consider this one. Thanks!

Comment: Condition i) implies Condition ii).

Comment: It may be useful to note that your property *i* implies *ii*. Also, the set of fixed points is closed, hence compact.

Comment: Bingo. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the set of all $f$ with the property that if $f(p)=p$ then $f'(p) \ne 1$.  Let $E$ be its complement, so that $f \in E$ iff there exists $p$ with $f(p)=p$ and $f'(p)=1$.  Let us show that $E$ is closed in $C^1([0,1])$.

Suppose $f_n \in E$ and $f_n \to f$ in $C^1$-norm; we must show $f \in E$.  By definition of $E$, for each $n$ there exists $p_n$ such that $f_n(p_n) = p_n$ and $f'(p_n)=1$.  Since $[0,1]$ is compact, we may pass to a subsequence and assume that $p_n$ converges to some point $p$.  Now $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, so $f_n(p_n) \to f(p)$ and hence $f(p)=p$.  Also, $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$, so $f_n'(p_n) \to f'(p)$ and hence $f'(p)=1$.  So $f \in E$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks!  I tend to find it easier to make topological arguments using sequences when possible, and "closed" has a nicer definition using sequences than "open", so that's why I thought of taking the complement.

Comment: I started writing a very tedious 'point-based' solution, then saw your solution and gave up :-).